# JSONDecodeError while merging JSON

Tags: python, json, glob

I am trying to merge multiple .json to one json file

code:

```
import glob, json
read_files = glob.glob("*.json")
output_list = []
for f in read_files:
    with open(f, "rb") as infile:
        output_list.append(json.load(infile))
all_items = []
for json_file in output_list:
    all_items += json_file['value']
textfile_merged = open('merged.json', 'w')
json.dump({ "value": all_items }, textfile_merged)
textfile_merged.close()
```

i am getting the following error

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\JSON\merge.py", line 7,
> in <module>
>     output_list.append(json.load(infile))   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
>     return loads(fp.read(),   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
>     return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
>     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in
> raw_decode
>     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char
> 0)
```

Comment: One of the files is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that one of your JSON file is empty (without having `{}`) or it is not formatted properly.

make sure your empty json file is having `{}` It must work.
Good luck!

Comment: Thank you i found in one file the } was not closed